# FragmentManager - NullPointerException android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity which extends `SherlockFragment`
I am trying to obtain the fragmentmanager object

I get a nullpointer exception on this line

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

basically this activity itself is a fragment and i want to change the activity on the framelayout to some other fragment.

Thanks!

Comment: If that is the line that is throwing the `NullPointerException` then `getSherlockActivity()` is returning null.  Can you show more code?

Comment: maybe because my activity extends SherlockFragment and not sherlockActivity is there a workaround?

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763141/activity-is-null-when-passing-it-to-my-custom-adapter-class

Comment: If you're retrieving from a Fragment, then you should do getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

Answer (score 0):

Why not use getFragmentManager()?  Its listed in the methods list of Fragment in the support library, and returns the manager from this fragment's containing activity.  getSupportFragmentManager() is the method used in the FragmentActivity, not in Fragment.

Your question isn't very clear, but this seems like what you want to do, no?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()